# i updated my existing project to androidx but got ExampleInstrumentedTest--> getTargetContext error

Tags: android, androidx

When I updated my project to androidx then I've got following error

I also searched but can't find my answer, although project works fine

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    public void useAppContext() {
        // Context of the app under test.
        Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

        assertEquals("com.example.villagefoodsecrets", appContext.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

At this point, `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` shows that it is deprecated.

And `Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();`
.getTargetContext; is in red format looks like not existed. So what can I do here - should I just ignore this?

Comment: Check the imports for these elements

Comment: here is my error https://imgur.com/a/58O1LE0

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To use non-deprecated classes, add below in build.gradle (app module level)

```
androidTestImplementation ‘androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1’
```

Then replace below deprecated imports in ExampleInstrumentedTest class

```
import androidx.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
```

with

```
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry ;
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;
```

and to get a context use below:

for Java

```
 Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
```

For Kotlin

```
   val appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
```

wish this helps you

Comment: i can't i have less then 15 reputations

Comment: This worked great. Exactly what I needed to fix up my automation tests after upgrading an old project to AndroidX